# Add additional column in fullcaledar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar and want to add column in day and week agenda along with days. Is it possible in Full calendar.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

EDIT:

I am adding image for more explanation:
[image]

Comment: Please explain in more detail. Question is too vague

Comment: @charlietfl please see image for explanation http://202.141.226.123:8081/mdvision.IEHRQAWAN/fullcalendar.png

Comment: not going to be simple. Try running this in console and you will see `$('.fc-slats tr').each(function(){
  var $td=$('<td>').width(30).text('44');
  $(this).find('td:first').after($td)
  
})`

Comment: I did that in day view on demo site. Can probably run something similar in viewrender callback. Probably have to modify plugin for best results

Comment: Any example will be appreciated which is near to my requirement.